# Debug jQuery code in a dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Chrome latest version (8.0.552.215).

I have a web page with an hyperlink that, when clicked, open up a jquery dialog and makes an ajax call that return `HTML` markup. the ajax call, upon success, add the returned markup to the dialog.

The returned markup contains also some jquery code to execute upon `$(document).ready()`.

How can I debug that code inside the dialog?

**EDIT:**

I have added the `debugger;` directive to my script as per the @Gaby answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTabs").tabs();

    debugger;

    var auth = "<% = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]==null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value %>";
```

But unfortunately when the debugger stops at the directive I am not able to see the code that is executing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `debugger;` directive in your code to call the debugger at a specific point.
*you need to have the developer tools open :* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

(*For future reference remember that this works with firebug for firefox as well.*)

Have a look at http://www.nsbasic.com/app/technotes/TT10.htm#tracing

---

**Update**
*After comments and update to question.*

I don't think you can show the code in the debugger as it is in memory..

A *cumbersome* alternative would be use `console.log(..)` for the parts you want to debug.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this? I dont know that directive... thanks!

Comment: @Lorenzo, you put `debugger;` in your script. It is actually a programmatic breakpoint. So, whenever the execution reaches that line it will halt execution and bring forth the debugger, and you can continue with the normal debugging actions. So you can put it in the script that is being brought from the ajax call.

Comment: please have a look at my edit. The debugger stops correctly at the directive but it does not show me the actual executing code. Maybe because the code has been added dinamically to the DOM?

Comment: Hmm.. that is the problem with callbacks and anonymous functions. adding update.